# Cumulative product by group without groups' last row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a simple dataframe as the following:

```
n_obs = 3
dd = pd.DataFrame({
    'WTL_exploded': [0, 1, 2]*n_obs,
    'hazard': [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6,0.6,0.65],
}, index=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
dd
```

I want to group by the *index* and get the cumulative product of the `hazard` column. However, I want to multiply **all but the last element** of each group.

**Desired output:**

| index | hazard |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 0.12 |
| 2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.16 |
| 3 | 0.6 |
| 3 | 0.36 |

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = dd.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().iloc[:-1])
```

Or:

```
out = dd.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().iloc[:-1]).droplevel(1)
```

output:

```
   WTL_exploded  hazard
1             0    0.30
1             0    0.12
2             0    0.20
2             0    0.16
3             0    0.60
3             0    0.36
```

*NB. you can also use `lambda x: x.cumprod().head(-1)`.*

Comment: This is great, especially the `head(-1)` bit! Thanks a lot :) Just for completeness, is there a way to apply `cumprod` to the last column only? in practice, I would like to have exactly your result but with `WTL_exploded` populated as in the original table instead of all zeros

Comment: Yes, slice just before `apply`. `out = dd.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)['your_col'].apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().iloc[:-1])`

Comment: Sure, I meant if there is a way to get the whole dataframe with one column as-is and the other after `cumprod`. So far I just compute the cumulative product separately and then attach to a new dataframe: `pd.concat([dd.groupby(level=0)['WTL_exploded'].head(-1),
            dd.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)['hazard'].apply(lambda x: x.cumprod().iloc[:-1])], axis=1)`. 
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is a bit intricate but works for the test case.

First, get rid of the last row of each group:

```
ff = dd.groupby(lambda x:x, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1])
ff
```

Then, restore the original index, group-by again and use pandas `cumprod`:

```
ff.reset_index().set_index('level_1').groupby(lambda x:x).cumprod()
```

Is there a more direct way?